# How to find associated Azure account with virtual machine ip adress

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine

I have virtual machine ssh login **ssh: azureuser@vm-ip-adress**. Last days the VM(Virtual Machine ) not responding.I want to find associated Azure account info to solve this problem.But i cant find which email is associated with this VM.

Comment: What do you mean associated Azure account? Do you want to find the account to log into your Azure VM?

Comment: Yes Azure account which the virtual machine is configured on

Comment: Is there anybody else in your subscription where the VM located?

Comment: No just my VMs located on that subscription